# IrfanView Startup Default File Type(s)

Tags: irfanview

My apologies if this has been answered before or is intuitively obvious.

After upgrading to V4.60 64 Bit, IrfanView starts up with a random default file type like "All Supported Sound Files" or "XCF - GIMP File Format".  All I Want is "All Supported Graphics Files".

This always happens after a reboot and sometimes even if IrfanView is closed and restarted.
It never had this issue before the upgrade.

Thanks,

--- sam

Comment: What do you mean  by "startup default type"? If you open a JPEG, default is to *save* as JPEG. If the last file you saved was PNG, the next time IrfanView starts, it will offer to save as PNG. If that is *not* the behavior, its settings aren't being retained. Perhaps it needs to be installed by current user?

Comment: Uninstall IrfanView, get the newest 64-bit version, restart and install the new version. No issue here as you describe.

Comment: @John the op is only 2 builds behind the stable 64-bit release...

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem the OP has has never shown up here. I have had IrfanView for a long time. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: So you're getting the "first run" prompt each time you start IrfanView? If so, John's suggestion is a good one.